# How to set focus for a composite field in dynamics crm 2013?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013, setfocus

I'm trying to set focus on the address1_postalcode field during the contact form load event. However when the script is run it throws an error.

Code:

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('address1_postalcode').setFocus();
```

And here is the error message:

[image]

I want to seek your kind help/suggestion in this manner to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that your code

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('address1_postalcode')
```

is returning null.  Try:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("address1_postalcode").setFocus();
```

http://crmorion.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-set-focus-on-control-in-crm-2013.html

Answer (score 0):

The most likely scenario is that the field you are referencing is not on your form.  Keep in mind, since CRM 2013 the address fields have been combined into a composite field, and I don't think you can directly access fields within a composite field.

You can add your field ('address1_postalcode') as a separate field on the form, then your code will work.

Note that using this approach results in some strange scenarios where the user may update your address1_postalcode field and these changes won't be reflected in the new composite address field.